# Java - Most suitable data structure for finding the most frequent element

Tags: java, string, data-structures

My program contains algorithms that output text (String). Eventually I want to print out the word that occurred the most. But before I do this, I need to store it in a data structure. So I was wondering what data structure is the best (easy and efficient) to store Strings and then be able to obtain the most frequent element? I don't want to use any libraries. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to use any libraries?

Comment: @sp00m - Each time I will get a word or maximum 2 words, I then want to store these words into a suitable data structure and then choose the most frequent one

Comment: `Map<String, Integer>` ?

Comment: Your title of the post is misleading. It can be thought of as `find the most frequently accessed` String, as in a cache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think any data structure does exactly this but here is how I would do it.

Maintain a `Map<String, Integer>` of each word to the number of times it was encountered and as you update the map keep track of the string corresponding to the largest number stored.  For example:

```java
String maxWord = null;
Integer maxCount = -1;
Map<String, Integer> wordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (String str : getMyProgramOutput()) {
  if (!wordCount.containsKey(str)) { wordCount.put(str, 0); }
  int count = wordCount.get(str) + 1;
  if (count > maxCount) {
    maxWord = str;
    maxCount = count;
  }
  wordCount.put(str, count);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Just a quick question, in the event that there are two elements with the same amount of occurance, what happens?

Comment: @Matt9Atkins: the first string encountered (by order of iterating the list of your program output) whose count reached the "max" value will be stored as the "maxWord".  If you want to change it to the last string then you can do `if (count >= maxCount)`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Map<String, Integer>`. Every time you enter a `String` increment the `Integer` (you might have to create your own `MutableInteger` class. When you're finished search it (or keep a running count)

Comment: No need for a MutableInteger class: `map.put(s, ++count);`…

Comment: How would I be able to get the most frequent element in a map?

Comment: @Matt9Atkins Iterate through it and find the word with the highest Integer value. O(n) + O(n)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just build a max heap where in each node will have the `String`and `integer_occurrence`. To get the most frequent word, get the root of the heap

Answer (score 0):

you might want to consider using dictionary in DB. Because such data normally has to be persisted into physical media to prevent from losing after system reboot. In this case, dictionary is helpful. Only thing you need to do is to set up a dictionary table and other table(s) for storing information like frequency and positioning and etc.